# Upgrading python and its packages to a newer version for my project

Tags: python, requirements.txt

For some context, my project uses python version 3.8 and has some packages in a requirements.txt file. I'm trying to upgrade the python version to 3.10 and also all the packages in my requirements.txt file to the latest possible version such that there are no conflicts between dependencies. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide a little more info on what OS you're using?

Comment: I'm using macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to say what will work best for you since you've given no info on your OS, and that thing you need is done differently on macOS and Windows.

If you're on macOS (this one could also work for Linux I guess), the best way to manage `python` versions is with `pyenv` and to update `python packages` with `pip-review`, both of which you can install via `brew`.

So first, you want to create a list of all your packages installed. To do that, you type `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt` in the terminal. The command creates a txt file in your home folder. In the file, you can see the names of all your packages installed, and it will look like this:

```
astroid==2.11.6
async-generator==1.10
attrs==21.4.0
autopep8==1.6.0
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
```

Secondly, to update your python version, you'll need to type `pyen install -l` in the terminal to get a list of all currently available versions of python. To install the one you need, let's say it's the most recent at the moment 3.10.5, type `pyenv install 3.10.5`. To set this version as a default one, type `pyenv global 3.10.5`. If you don't need your previous version of python, just type `pyenv uninstall` and the number of the version you want to delete after a space (it's really just like installing one).

Thirdly, to move all your previous packages in the newly installed python version, just type `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` in the terminal. The command will get the packages of the same versions you had before.

Lastly, to upgrade the packages to the most recent version, type `pip-review --auto`. It will fetch the latest versions available and install them with no more commands from you.

Now here's why I think `pip-review` works better than anything else I've tried so far: in case some dependencies are broken (i. e. a package you are using needs another package of an older version than you've just upgraded to), it will point that out in the terminal, and you could get the right one.

Comment: What if the packages in the requirements.txt file already have dependency conflicts for me? This seems specific for macOS as other people working on this project that run pip install on this requirements.txt file seem to have no issues.

Comment: You could try typing `pip3 check` for a list of broken requirements and then install the right versions with `pip3 install PACKAGE_NAME==VERSION`, e. g. `pip3 install jedi==0.17.2`

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that just you need to update your requirements file.
and run the requirements file. it will automatically update your all files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can update to Python3.10 and drop the previous `requirements.txt` into your project root directory.  From there you can run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the packages.

You can also run `pip install -U <package-name>` to update any package to the latest version.

Also, to re-generate a new `requirements.txt` file, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure there is no such thing as automatically updating dependencies in such way that there are no conflicts. Some dependencies may have changes that are not backward compatible and a complete test of all your project's features will be necessary whenever you change the version of anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an open-source project called [Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) that can help you maintain your packages and update them to recent versions